# Parity PoA step duration

Tags: parity, poa

I’m setting up a private blockchain using parity. I need to use PoA consensus with the maximum throughput possible.
What do you recommend to set the stepDuration value to? Can we set it to a very low number to achieve a high transaction throughput or id does have a side effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do you recommend to set the `stepDuration` value to?

In the discussion associated with Parity issue [#9586](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/9586), one of the Parity devs mentioned that block times of below 5 seconds are not recommended. I see that as being the lower limit to `stepDuration`. (Also note that you might want to use the `--force-sealing` option.)

(If you're experimenting with a high throughput, then this open issue might also be of use: [#9393](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/9393).)